# What happens if I call Start() two times on class System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Imagine that I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with 1000 ms interval.

If I call `Timer.Start()` method and after 500 ms I call again `Timer.Start()` what happens? The second `Start` call will reset the interval or not? Are there any side effects?

Comment: Well, Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for this question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The timer is already started, so a second call will not affect it.

Regardless, this is **easy** to test.

Comment: You could put "easy" in bold :)

Comment: @Drake - such as? Calling `Start` is like setting `Enabled` to `true`.

Comment: @Oded: Saeed downvoted, he misinterpreted the output of Reflector. ;)

Comment: @Bobby - Yeah, and he also realized his mistake :)

Comment: @Oded: Yes, I just wasn't sure if you saw his comment/answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Start() just sets the Enabled property to true. If the Enabled property is already set to true it just sets Enabled to true again and keeps going.

Likewise, Stop() sets Enabled to false.

Answer (score 2):

It won't affected anything...

See this code

```
  class TimerTest
{
   static int i = 0;
    static void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(i);
        i++;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        // interval = 500ms
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 500;
        tmr.Elapsed += Tick;
        tmr.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        tmr.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        tmr.Stop();
        Console.ReadLine();
        tmr.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        tmr.Dispose(); // This both stops the timer and cleans up.
    }
}
```

once u started, if Enter return the second start won't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Those answering that Start() "just sets the Enabled property to true" are overlooking that Enabled is a property and that all of the start logic is in the set accessor. So, there is no "just" about it.
Looking at the reference source makes it clear that if you set Enabled to the same value that it already has then **nothing** happens, it's a nop.